# How to design custom messaging system with MassTransit?

Tags: masstransit

I want to design a messaging system with *MassTransit* according to below image. When I used *Masstransit* and *ReceiveEndpoint* configuration, an exchange and a queue created per each action, which increases the number of exchange and queue. And with the increase of processes, it causes confusion for me. Is there a solution to solve this problem and design a messaging system according to below image?

[image]

I expect to be able to design as shown above

Answer (score 0):

MassTransit supports the configuration of DIRECT exchanges, using routing keys to route message beyond the default type-based routing. There is a [sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Direct) that gives some guidance, and likely a few questions and answers here as well as GitHub discussions.

Comment: Thank you for your attention and response and I completely understand. I've seen this example before and I think I didn't explain my problem well. I'm designing a large-scale application and may use an Saga pattern with multiple states throughout the application. In this case, according to the image of the links below, I will have a large number of Exchanges and Queues. That makes management difficult. For this reason, I want to design a model similar to the image model of the above question. https://iili.io/HHfyI7R.jpg - https://iili.io/HHfyzdv.jpg

Comment: You'll still have a large number of exchanges and queues. Using content-based routing necessitates are larger number of exchanges/queues.